# MudCheckbox event call

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

Currently I have this:

```
 @foreach (var rol in Rollenlist)
 {
    <InputCheckbox class="form-check" @bind-Value=@rol.IsSelected @onclick="(() => RolSelected(rol.Id.Value))" />
 }
```

and

```
void RolSelected(int id) 
{
  ...
}
```

I would like to use MudCheckbox:

```
<MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@rol.IsSelected" Label="@rol.Name" LabelPosition="LabelPosition.Start" Color="Color.Primary"
                               Size="MudBlazor.Size.Large" CheckedChanged="RolSelected(rol.Id.Value)"></MudCheckBox>
```

But it is not working.

```
RZ1OO1O: The component parameter 'CheckedChanged' is used two or more times for this component. Parameters must be unique (case-insensitive). The component parameter 'CheckedChanged' is
generated by the '@bind-Checked' directive attribute.

CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'void' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### First error

`@bind-Checked` is the shorthand of using `Checked` and `CheckedChanged`, that's why you're seeing the first error because you can't use both.

#### Second error

`CheckedChanged` is an `EventCallback<T>` so:-

1. `T` should be declared, i.e. `T="bool"`.
2. When the checkbox changes the `CheckedChanged` fires the `T` event payload. If you place the handler method like `CheckedChanged="RolSelected"`, then the method will implicitly receive the changed `T` value that the event fires.

```
<MudCheckBox Checked="@rol.IsSelected" CheckedChanged="RolSelected" T="bool"/>
    void RolSelected(bool newValue) // implicitly receives the value
    {
        rol.IsSelected = newValue;
    }
```

However, since you need to pass additional parameters to the method then you need to explicitly pass the changed value to the method along with other parameters.

```
<MudCheckBox Checked="@rol.IsSelected" T="bool"
             CheckedChanged="(newValue => RolSelected(newValue,rol.Id.Value))"/>

@code{
    
    void RolSelected(bool newValue,int id) 
    {
        // you need to change the variable in Checked
        rol.IsSelected = newValue;
        // rest of your code
    }
}
```

*Note*: If you use `CheckedChanged` then you must change the variable you have placed in `Checked` as it will not auto update like when using `@bind-Checked`. **Unless** you're handling binding across multiple components.